Extreme points of set of probability measures
Let $K$ be a compact and Hausdorff topological space. Denote by $\mathcal{M}(K)$ the Banach space of regular complex Borel measures on $K$, and by $\mathcal{P}(K)$ the subset of $\mathcal{M}(K)$ consisting of probability measures.
Prove that $\text{Ext}(\mathcal{P}(K))$ is the set $\{\mu \in \mathcal{P}(K) : \mu \text{ is } \{0,1\}\text{-valued}\}$. ($\text{Ext}(\mathcal{P}(K))$ is the set of extreme points of $\mathcal{P}(K)$).
My attempt
1) A comment first: When we say $\mu \text{ is } \{0,1\}\text{-valued}$, that means that $\forall A \in \mathcal{B}(K)$ we have either $\mu(A) = 1$ or $\mu(A) = 0$, right? Also, can I write instead of $\forall A \in \mathcal{B}(K)$, $\forall A \subset K$?
First, let us prove $\text{Ext}(\mathcal{P}(K)) \subset \{\mu \in \mathcal{P}(K) : \mu \text{ is } \{0,1\}\text{-valued}\}$. Suppose that $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(K)$ is not $\{0,1\}\text{-valued}$. Then there exists $A \subset K$ and $t \in (0,1)$ such that $\mu(A) = t$. Let us see that $\mu$ cannot belong to $\text{Ext}(\mathcal{P}(K))$. Observe that $\mu$ can be written as:
$$
\mu = \frac{1}{2}(\mu + \nu) + \frac{1}{2}(\mu - \nu),
$$
where $\nu \in \mathcal{M}(K)$ is defined as $\nu(B) = (1 - t)\mu(B \cap A) - t\mu(B \setminus A)$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(K)$. Let us verify that both $\mu + \nu$ and $\mu - \nu$ are probability measures. We use that $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(K)$ if and only if $\mu(K) = 1$ and $\|\mu\| = 1$. First, note that $\nu(K) = 0$:
$$
\nu(K) = (1 - t)\mu(K \cap A) - t\mu(K \setminus A) = (1 - t)\mu(A) - t(1 -\mu(A)) = 0,
$$
so $(\mu + \nu)(K) = \mu(K) + \nu(K) = 1$, and similarly for $(\mu - \nu)$. It remains to show that $\|\mu + \nu\| = 1$ and $\|\mu - \nu\| = 1$. We have:
$$
\|\mu + \nu\| =  |\mu + \nu|(K) \geq | \mu(K) + \nu(K) | = 1,
$$
and since the total variation is a norm we also have
$$  
\|\mu + \nu\| \leq \|\mu \| + \|\nu\| = 1 + \|\nu\|.
$$
2) But, how can I conclude with this?
Finally, observe that $\nu \neq 0$, because for the set $A$, we have
$$ 
\nu(A) = (1 - t)\mu(A) \neq 0.
$$
3) Is this the right set to pick? Do we have $A \in \mathcal{B}(K)$?
(Maybe I am wrong and should define $\nu$ as $\nu(B) = (1 - t)\nu(B \cap A) - t\nu(B \setminus A)$).
Next, let us prove $\{\mu \in \mathcal{P}(K) : \mu \text{ is } \{0,1\}\text{-valued}\} \subset \text{Ext}(\mathcal{P}(K))$. Let $t \in (0,1)$ and suppose that $\mu \in \{\mu \in \mathcal{P}(K) : \mu \text{ is } \{0,1\}\text{-valued}\}$ satisfies $\mu = t a + (1-t)b$ with $a, b \in \mathcal{P}(K)$. We want to show that $\mu = a = b$. Since $\mu$ is $\{0,1\}\text{-valued}$, for any $A \in \mathcal{B}(K)$ we have either $\mu(A) = 1$ or $\mu(A) = 0$. In the first case:
$$  
\mu(A) = t a(A) + (1-t)b(A) = 1
$$
and, since $a$ and $b$ are probability measures and $t \in (0,1)$, it must hold that
$$  
\mu(A) = a(A) = b(A) = 1.
$$
In the second case:
$$  
\mu(A) = t a(A) + (1-t)b(A) = 0
$$
and again, since $a$ and $b$ are probability measures and $t \in (0,1)$, it must hold that
$$  
\mu(A) = a(A) = b(A) = 0.
$$
Hence $\mu = a = b$.
4) Is this correct?

Seems correct. Concerning the first part  I would use $$\mu(B)=t{\mu(A\cap B)\over t}+(1-t){\mu (A'\cap B)\over 1-t}$$ where $A'=K\setminus A.$ Hence $\mu$ is a convex combination of two probability measures.
